# SQL Server: How to find and replace data in xml by XQuery

Tags: sql-server

I have XML stored in a SQL Server table. There is a `GroupKey` element in the XML and `GroupKey` has a few other data separated by `~` sign. `GroupKey` looks like

```
<GroupKey>Consensus Model~Total Revenue~TRIN~NBM~~1~ZB-P1</GroupKey>
```

`GroupKey` has:

1. Consensus Model is Section
2. Total Revenue is LineItem
3. TRIN is XFundCode

and rest of data separated by `~` are not a concern for my case.

I have to find out line item in `GroupKey`. If match found then replace xfundcode with new xfundcode in xml and update the whole xml in table column.

I will create a stored procedure where I will send line item and xfundcode both.

This is my code and I am weak in XQuery that is why I could not do what I am trying to achieve.

```
DECLARE @xml xml
DECLARE @li varchar(max) ='Segment Detail'
DECLARE @newXfundCode varchar(max) ='TEST'

CREATE TABLE #tmpData (id INT, xmldata xml)  

INSERT INTO #tmpData (id, xmldata) 
VALUES (1,N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<PWR_ViewAll>
<dgvViewAll_Vertical>
  <Section_x0020_>ZB-P1</Section_x0020_>
  <LineItem>B. Riley FBR Inc.</LineItem>
  <Revise_x0020_Date>08-21-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
  <GroupKey>Consensus Model~Total Revenue~TRIN~NBM~~1~ZB-P1</GroupKey>
</dgvViewAll_Vertical>
<dgvViewAll_Vertical>
  <Section_x0020_>CL</Section_x0020_>
  <LineItem>Deutsche Bank</LineItem>
  <Revise_x0020_Date>02-28-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
  <GroupKey>Segment Detail~Total Revenue~TEST~NBM~~1~CL</GroupKey>
</dgvViewAll_Vertical>
</PWR_ViewAll>')

SELECT @xml=xmldata from #tmpData where ID=1


SELECT col.value('(GroupKey/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/PWR_ViewAll/dgvViewAll_Vertical') AS tab (col)
WHERE  CHARINDEX(@li, col.value('(GroupKey/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))>0 

Drop table #tmpData
```

I post the question in **Microsoft QA** and i got an answer. the answer i could not understand because i am weak in XQuery. Hence i do not understand the answer that why i am posting the same issue in SO.

I also like to post the answer received from [@yitzhakkhabinsky-0887](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/yitzhakkhabinsky-0887/)

Answer is below which i got from **Microsoft QA**

```
DECLARE @xml XML
, @li VARCHAR(MAX) ='Segment Detail'
, @newXfundCode VARCHAR(MAX) ='newXfundCode'
, @separator CHAR(1) = '~';

DECLARE @tmpData TABLE (id INT, xmldata XML);  

INSERT INTO @tmpData(id, xmldata) VALUES 
(1, N'<PWR_ViewAll>
<dgvViewAll_Vertical>
<Section_x0020_>ZB-P1</Section_x0020_>
<LineItem>B. Riley FBR Inc.</LineItem>
<Revise_x0020_Date>08-21-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
<GroupKey>Consensus Model~Total Revenue~TRIN~NBM~~1~ZB-P1</GroupKey>
</dgvViewAll_Vertical>
<dgvViewAll_Vertical>
<Section_x0020_>CL</Section_x0020_>
<LineItem>Deutsche Bank</LineItem>
<Revise_x0020_Date>02-28-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
<GroupKey>Segment Detail~Total Revenue~WOW~NBM~~1~CL</GroupKey>
</dgvViewAll_Vertical>
</PWR_ViewAll>');

SET @xml= (SELECT xmldata FROM @tmpData WHERE ID=1);

;WITH rs AS
(
SELECT col.value('(GroupKey/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Before]
FROM @xml.nodes('/PWR_ViewAll/dgvViewAll_Vertical') AS tab (col)
--WHERE  CHARINDEX(@li, col.value('(GroupKey/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) > 0
)
SELECT *, REPLACE(TRY_CAST('<root><r>' + 
REPLACE([before], @separator, '</r><r>') + 
'</r></root>' AS XML).query('<root>
{
for $x in /root/r
let $pos := count(/root/r[. << $x[1]]) + 1
return if ($pos=3 and root/*[position() = 2 and ./text()="Total Revenue"]) then <r>{sql:variable("@newXfundCode")}</r>
else $x
}
</root>').query('
for $i in /root/r
return if ($i is (/root/r[last()])[1]) then string($i)
else concat($i, sql:variable("@separator"))
').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),@separator + SPACE(1), @separator) AS [After]
FROM rs;
```

**My request to all sql server expert** that please see my scenario and give me answer to find and update data in xml as a easy way which a sql server beginner can understand.

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server has a `modify()` method for XML columns that [can be used to replace node values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml). I am missing a clear example of sample input data (the two code snippets have a different starting XML) and expected result. Also, if you want to filter on the LineItem part of the `<GroupKey>` node, then including another separate `<LineItem>` node in the sample data is very confusing. Aim for a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xml xml
DECLARE @li varchar(max) ='Segment Detail'
DECLARE @newXfundCode varchar(max) ='TEST'

CREATE TABLE #tmpData (id INT, xmldata xml)  

INSERT INTO #tmpData (id, xmldata) 
VALUES (1,N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<PWR_ViewAll>
<dgvViewAll_Vertical>
  <Section_x0020_>ZB-P1</Section_x0020_>
  <LineItem>B. Riley FBR Inc.</LineItem>
  <Revise_x0020_Date>08-21-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
  <GroupKey>Consensus Model~Total Revenue~TRIN~NBM~~1~ZB-P1</GroupKey>
</dgvViewAll_Vertical>
<dgvViewAll_Vertical>
  <Section_x0020_>CL</Section_x0020_>
  <LineItem>Deutsche Bank</LineItem>
  <Revise_x0020_Date>02-28-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
  <GroupKey>Segment Detail~Total Revenue~RD_100~NBM~~1~CL</GroupKey>
</dgvViewAll_Vertical>
</PWR_ViewAll>')

SELECT @xml=xmldata from #tmpData where ID=1

declare 
    @oldGroupKeyvalue varchar(100), 
    @newGroupKeyValue varchar(100);

SELECT @oldGroupKeyvalue = col.value('(GroupKey/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/PWR_ViewAll/dgvViewAll_Vertical') AS tab (col)
WHERE  CHARINDEX(@li, col.value('(GroupKey/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))>0;


--@newGroupKeyValue = @oldgroupkeyvalue but stuff/"replace" string between 2nd&3rd ~ with @newXfundCode
select  @newGroupKeyValue = 
--"replace/stuff" the old xfundcode := all chars from position of 2nd ~ (+1) till position of the 2nd ~ (minus 1) with an empty string
stuff(@oldGroupKeyvalue, 
--starting from position of 2nd ~ +1
charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, 1)+1)+1,
--as many characters as exist between 3rd ~ and 2nd ~ (excluding ~)
charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, 1)+1)+1)-1
-
charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, 1)+1),
--stuff the new xfundcode
@newXfundCode
);

--test
select @oldGroupKeyValue as oldgroupkeyvalue, @newGroupKeyValue as newgroupkeyvalue;


--test
select @xml as oldxml;

--modify xml, replace the text of GroupKey element whose text equals @oldGroupKeyValue with @newGroupKeyValue
--if newGroupKeyValue is not null etc...
set @xml.modify('
  replace value of (/PWR_ViewAll/dgvViewAll_Vertical/GroupKey[.=sql:variable("@oldGroupKeyValue")]/text())[1]  
  with sql:variable("@newGroupKeyValue") 
'
);

select @xml as newxml;


--update #tmpData set xmldata = @xml where ID=1;
--select * from #tmpData;

Drop table #tmpData
```

Comment: The code you provided...It is not checking if the `2nd token contains "Total Revenue" value or not.` please rectify if required.

Comment: you could change the where clause (that you have provided)  to search/get the first groupkey value which has 'Total Revenue': `WHERE  CHARINDEX(@li, col.value('(GroupKey/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))>0;`  --> `WHERE  CHARINDEX(@li+'~Total Revenue~', col.value('(GroupKey/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))>0;`